# Issues with reading Bluetooth messages in Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, arduino, bluetooth

Description: I'm developing a Flutter app that communicates with an HC-05 Bluetooth module. The module is configured properly and has been tested with another app called Bluetooth Terminal. However, I'm having issues with reading the messages that are sent from the module to the phone in my Flutter app.

For example, when the module sends the message "status", I should receive either "closed" or "open", but I'm getting the message split into two parts like "c" and "losed". Similarly, when I send a message like "F7 6B A4 7A", I get the message split into multiple parts like "A" ,ccess denied, UID tag: 80 63", "2B 32 is", "not allowe" ,d to open", "Lock 2".

I'm using the **`BluetoothSerial`** library to communicate with the Bluetooth module, and my code uses the **`listenForMessages()`** function to listen for incoming messages. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
StreamSubscription<List<int>> _inputSubscription;
StreamController<String> _messageController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

Stream<String> listenForMessages() {
  if (!isConnected) {
    return Stream.empty();
  }
  if (_inputSubscription == null) {
    _inputSubscription = connection.input.listen((data) {
      String message = utf8.decode(data).trim();
      _messageController.add(message);
    });
  }
  return _messageController.stream;
}
```

for arduino part :

```
void sendStatusAndRecords()
{

// Function to send status and records via bluetooth

  // Check if the lock is currently open or closed
  String lockStatus = digitalRead(LOCK_PIN) == HIGH ? "open" : "closed";
  // Construct a message with the lock status and some example records
  String record = lockStatus;
  //String record = "Records: \n Lock is " + lockStatus + "\n";
  bthc05.println(record);

}
```